# Decompose a $2\times 2$ matrix to a combination of rotation matrices

Tags: matrices, triangles, rotations

## The background

I encounter this problem when I try to analyze the planar transformation of a 2D triangle. We ignore the translational shift in this problem.

Consider a 2D triangle whose edge vectors are $\vec x_0, \vec x_1\in \mathbb R^2$, these two vectors are coming from the same vertex, equivalent to the origin.

Apply an arbitrary transformation $T \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 2}$ on this triangle and we get $\vec x_0', \vec x_1'$, which construct a new triangle.
$$
[\vec x_0', \vec x_1'] = T [\vec x_0, \vec x_1]
$$

## My thinking

Then I just think: a transformation from $x_0$ to $x_0'$ is simply $x_0' = s_0 R_0 x_0$, where $s_0$ is a scaling factor and $R_0$ a rotation matrix. so that I can get:
$$
\begin{cases}
\vec x_0' = s_0 R_0 x_0 \\
\vec x_1' = s_1 R_1 x_0 \\
\end{cases}
$$

## My question

The transformation $T$ has 4 DOFs. and $s_0, s_1, R_0, R_1$ also has 4 DOFs. So it is possible to build a relationship between them.

What is the relationship between this two stuff? How to parameterize $T$ in $s_0, s_1, R_0, R_1$? which is
$$
T = T(s_0, s_1, R_0, R_1) ?
$$

Comment: $R_i$ only has 1 degree of freedom - $\theta$.

Comment: Also , unless my mental picture is incorrect (which is probably the case), $s$ and $R$ is not enough to describe all

Comment: Sorry for my unclear explanation. $R_0$ has one, $R_1$ has one, $s_0$ has one, $s_1$ has one, sum for 4.

Comment: Then the problem becomes trivial, you want to find a rotation then a scaling that maps $\vec{x_0}$ to $\vec{x_0}'$, which is achieved by rotating $\arg(\vec{x_0}') - \arg(\vec{x_0})$ then scaling by $\frac{|\vec{x_0}'|}{|\vec{x_0}|}$.

Comment: Maybe my statement is a little misleading. The transformation of a pair of vector $x_0, x_1$ to $x_0', x_1'$ fully determined a transformation matrix $T$ which can be easily get by inversion. This is one of my point. And another point: I can individually convert $x_0$ to $x_0'$ by $s_0 R_0$ and $x_1$ to $x_1'$ by $s_1 R_1$. From this point, I can achiveve the same goal by two way, $T$ and $s_0, R_0, s_1, R_1$. And I am curious about the relationship between  these two methods. ;-)